# Java : Pass class via argument

Tags: java, android

Please look at the following code:

```
public class Hello
{
    public void onSayHello()
    {
    }
}


public void test()
{
    sayHello(new Hello()
    {
         public void onSayHello()
         {
              //do something
         }
    });
}

public void sayHello(Hello hello)
{
    Toast.makeText(context, "Hello world");
    hello.onSayHello();
}
```

Is this good solution?
Is this a callback solution or a listener solution? How is it called?

Comment: school assignment? that listener

Comment: Listener or call back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an anonymous, derived class. It's not the preferred solution if you want to receive a callback. Instead use an interface:

```
public class Hello {

    public interface OnHelloSaidListener {
        void onHelloSaid();
    }

}

public void test() {
    sayHello(new OnHelloSaidListener() {
        @Override
        public void onHelloSaid() {
            // Do somth
        }
    });
}

public void sayHello(OnHelloSaidListener callback) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Hello world");
    callback.onHelloSaid();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the between callback, handler, listener ?